# How to chain two geometric objects using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

how can we connect two speheres using a line?
I would like it to act like to balls connected with a rope or something elastic
Can anyone point to some samples?

Answer (score 2):

To draw an arrow between two points is straightforward:

```
var startPoint = new THREE.Vector3(10,20,30);
var endPoint   = new THREE.Vector3(70,80,90);
var direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(endPoint, startPoint).normalize();
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction, startPoint, startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint), 0xCC0000 );
scene.add(arrow);
```

To draw just a line is a bit trickier:

```
var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
lineGeometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(10,20,30), new THREE.Vector3(70,80,90) );
lineGeometry.computeLineDistances();
var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xCC0000 } );
var line = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry, lineMaterial );
scene.add(line);
```

Comment: Geometry was removed from THREE. How to achieve this with BufferGeoemtry?

Answer (score 0):

What I was referring to requires a physics engine.

Examples can be found here
http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the "elastic feel" for a line between two objects, you could use a `BezierCurve`. There are few different types of them included in `Three.js`.
For example, look at [this link](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Curves/CubicBezierCurve3) for more information.

I didn't quite understood what you've meant in your own answer, about physics engines, but if you intended producing a horizontal rope like line, you'd better use a few `THREE.Line`s connected and activate a physics engine, such as `cannon.js`. I think you'd better use [THREEx.cannon.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.cannonjs) for easy integration between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Straight red line example with `BufferGeometry`

Threejs **r125** update after, [see details](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401)

```
let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints([
  new THREE.Vector3(-5, 5, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(5, 5, 0)
])

let line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 }))
scene.add(line)
```